Using the SUM() in the ON Clause of the Join
I have 3 tables named students, student_courses and grades. And for each student I need to calculate their overall GPA. So I'm a bit stuck. :(
students table



student_id
student_name




77
Pepe LePew



student_courses



student_id
course_id
percent_grade




77
101
95.7


77
202
85.9


77
303
77.1


77
404
66.6



grades



from_percent
to_percent
letter_grade
GPA




0
69
F
0


70
72
C-
1.67


73
76
C
2.0


77
79
C+
2.33


80
82
B-
2.67


83
86
B
3.0


87
89
B+
3.33


90
92
A-
3.67


93
96
A
4.0


97
100
A+
4.0



Here's my query that is getting an error. (Error Code 1111. Invalid use of group function) I happen to be using MySQL but would be happy to get a standard SQL solution.
SELECT student_id, student_name,
(select g.GPA      
 from course_student AS cs    
 inner join Grades AS g ON (sum(cs.percent_grade) / count(*)) BETWEEN g.from_percent AND g.to_percent
 where cs.student_id = students.id) As GPA 
FROM students 

The expected result would be a listing of all of the students in the student table and their corresponding overall GPA



student_id
GPA




77
2.67



Update 1.
I just got it to work for a single student. But I need it to work for all of the students in the students table. Here's the code for a single student.
select g.GPA, g.from_percent, g.to_percent
 from course_student AS cs    
 inner join Grades AS g 
 where cs.student_id = 77
 group by g.GPA, g.from_percent, g.to_percent
 HAVING (sum(cs.percent_grade) / count(*)) BETWEEN g.from_percent AND g.to_percent 


Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/LqKCZTZl

Please add the expected result to your question and explain the logic you need. Don't write comments, edit your question instead. If you need a solution for different students, you should add them to your sample data accordingly.

Sample table data is great, but a [mcve] is also supposed to include the expected result.

Updated the question with the table of expected result. :) Thank you

We can create a StudentGrades CTE that groups by student and calculates the average grade from all of their courses. Then we can then use AvgGrade to join on the grades table.
WITH StudentGrades as
(
  SELECT s.student_id, s.student_name, SUM(percent_grade) as TotalGrade, count(*) as CourseCount, CAST(SUM(percent_grade) / count(*) AS INT)  as AvgGrade
  FROM students  s
  INNER JOIN student_courses c on s.student_id=c.student_id
  GROUP BY s.student_id, s.student_name
)
SELECT sg.student_id, sg.student_name, g.GPA
FROM StudentGrades sg
INNER JOIN grades g on g.from_percent <= sg.AvgGrade AND g.to_percent >= sg.AvgGrade

fiddle



student_id
student_name
GPA




69
Bart McEndree
4


77
Pepe LePew
2.67




Brilliant. MY SQL sophistication does not stretch this far, so I definitely would not have gotten there on my own. :) Marking it as accepted answer.

Why do that strange divsion? We can simply use AVG(percent_grade). Since you don't check whether counts equals zero, you're on risk of an exception.

The design has a few gotchas. Why have a GPA column or a Grades table at all? Wouldn't the AvgGrade be more accurate?  If a AvgGrade was 69.9 the grade would not be found because there is no record to match that value. This is why I converted it to INT.

@Jonas Metzler I was keeping with the style of LostAndConfused and trying to keep as much of their original attempt as possible. Your suggestion is a good optimization step.

@BartMcEndree It's not just "optimization", it's avoiding possible divide by zero exceptions. I would also do some other changes, so I extended your fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/F-wShEA5 Note that my intention is just to improve your answer, not to say it was bad. Your query is on the right track, anyway. Maybe you could have a look and think if it's helpful or not for you/for OP.

You are both very helpful. Thank you. @Bart I will update the grades table to include 69.99 that you caught. I posted data straight from my users without doing tech review on it. LOL

@Jonas wonderful suggestion. I stripped the SQL somewhat before posting it here, which ruled out the possibility of dividing by zero. But the fact that it simplifies the query is nice as it makes it easier to read and maintain.
